# How can I set graphical parameters (par()) and structure options (strOptions()) in a knitr document?

Tags: r, knitr

I am working on a knitr-sweave document and have found that global R options like

```
par(lwd=3)
```

and

```
strOptions(strict.width='cut')
```

do not take effect in later code chunks.  I can specify these options as arguments each time I plot() or str(), so it's not a huge problem.  I'm just wondering if anyone has any insight into this.  Should I be caching the code chunk where I set these options?  I call some libraries in early code chunks and set variables in others and they all seem to be accessible "globally" (i.e. in later code chunks).

Comment: `par` is only supposed to affect the current graphical device. I am a bit surprised that `strOptions` doesn't have a durable effect.

Comment: I get that par is for current devices, but why doesn't something like `op <- par(pch = '$', col = green)` work in a subsequent chunks by calling `op` again?

Comment: @rawr I feel the same as @BondedDust. For `par()`, it is because knitr opens a new device for each code chunk. Perhaps I should record `par()` throughout the session to make the settings persistent. Personally I often use a chunk hook to set par(), e.g. https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/c3716ee5b980af595dd0f3eeef3e34092f5a86ca/inst/examples/knitr-manual.Rnw#L48-L50

Answer (score 1):

I believe I can help you with setting `strOptions` globally. Just set your `str` options as a list under `options`, like this:

```
options(str = list(strict.width = "cut"))
```